# What can I do when a Python virtual environment doesn't find modules?

Tags: python, virtualenv

On Ubuntu 16.04 I created a virtual environment called `venv` and inside the `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages` I have `nltk` and `nltk-3.2.2.dist-info` as normal.

However, when I activate the virtual environment using `source venv/bin/activate` and run a Python script that contains `import nltk`, I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

With "pip list" you can always check which packages are installed in your venv.

```
(venv)user@home:~/venv$ pip list
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (32.3.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

First activate the venv, then install the dependencies, e.g., `pip install nltk`.

The packages will then live inside the venv folder.

Answer (score 0):

Using vscode, I got that issue when trying to run my program with the default "run python file" or "debug python file" buttons, even when I had the venv activated.

I found out it was because all those buttons do is run a command which uses the default python in your system to run your file instead of the one in the venv. To fix that, you need to run the program manually: `python path_to_your/file_name.py`

Edit: after enabling venv, you can press `ctrl+shift+p`, then type `Python:Select Interpreter` and choose the python interpreter in the venv. Now, the run and debug buttons should work as normal.